# how to loop files in a folder which has space in it

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code to copy files from a list. When the path of the files which the folder name has no space, it works perfectly. But the folder names could have space sometimes, how can I improve the code to handle the folder name with space

```
FOR /F %%a in (find_file_list.txt) DO COPY "%%a" "C:\test\%%~nxa"
```

Basically, in this find_file_list.txt, there list all files with path

```
c:\abc\def\12345.txt

c:\abc\def\12346.txt

c:\abc\def\12347.txt
```

the above code copy all these three files into folder of test and works fine.
Now when find_file_list.txt change, actually the real folder name has space in it, like

```
c:\ab c\de f\12345.txt

c:\ab c\de f\12346.txt

c:\ab c\de f\12347.txt
```

the above code not working anymore...
any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to select the `delims` you want to split on:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (find_file_list.txt) DO COPY "%%a" "C:\test\%%~nxa"
```

Default delimeters are whitespace, if your file contains it, it will split on the whitepace.
Simply add `"delims="` to change it to take the full string.

Answer (score 0):

To output each non empty line in the file, you should ensure that you stipulate either `all tokens` or `no delimiters`, *(you may also need, depending upon your task, to prevent the exclusion of lines beginning with a specific character, the default `For` behavior is to ignore all lines which begin with a semicolon, **`;`**)*.
*My preference in this instance is to stipulate `all tokens`; this, unlike stipulating `no`delimiters, will remove all leading whitespace from every line, (this would prevent files carrying accidental leading spaces from being picked up).*

You cannot `copy` a file which does not exist, you could supress any error when trying to do so by using `2>Nul`, but I would consider it better practice to see if the file exists first.

When you `copy` a file you need provide only the destination, *(you only need to provide the file name if you're changing it)*.

Instead of using the `Copy` command you could instead use the `XCopy` command, this has the benefit of creating the destination directory, *(subject to permissions)*, if it doesn't already exist.

Here therefore is a batch file example:

```bat
@For /F UseBackTokens^=*EOL^= %%A In ("find_file_list.txt") Do @If Exist "%%A" XCopy "%%A" "C:\test\">Nul
```

…and a very slightly modified version to be run from the Command Prompt:

```dos
For /F UseBackTokens^=*EOL^= %A In ("find_file_list.txt") Do @If Exist "%A" XCopy "%A" "C:\test\">Nul
```